# How to squish/merge multiple rows without transforming the data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   ['23', 'Pedro',  None  , 'Carla',  None  ,   None  ],
                   ['23',  None  ,  None  ,  None  , 'Tulia',   None  ],
                   ['23',  None  , 'Vindy',  None  ,  None  ,   None  ],
                   ['23',  None  ,  None  ,  None  ,  None  ,  'Wimpo'],
                   ['49',  None  , 'Vindy',  None  ,  None  ,   None  ],
                   ['49',  None  ,  None  , 'Carla',  None  ,  'Wimpo']
                  ],
                  columns = ['id', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

|  | id | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23 | Pedro |  | Carla |  |  |
| 1 | 23 |  |  |  | Tulia |  |
| 2 | 23 |  | Vindy |  |  |  |
| 3 | 23 |  |  |  |  | Wimpo |
| 4 | 49 |  | Vindy |  |  |  |
| 5 | 49 |  |  | Carla |  | Wimpo |

How can I squish/merge this dataframe resulting the following one?

|  | id | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23 | Pedro | Vindy | Carla | Tulia | Wimpo |
| 5 | 49 |  | Vindy | Carla |  | Wimpo |

Comment: `df.groupby('id',as_index=False).first()`?

Comment: Uau Quang, thats beautiful! My previous dataset had 17k rows now has 3k. Thank you!

Comment: Make an answare with this code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.ffill()).drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

Output:

```
   id      a      b      c      d      e
3  23  Pedro  Vindy  Carla  Tulia  Wimpo
5  49   None  Vindy  Carla   None  Wimpo
```